# Neo4j Apt Key Refused

Tags: linux, debian, database, apt

I am trying to install Neo4j on a Debian system, thus I have opened the page https://debian.neo4j.org/ and followed the instructions. I had no problem with the first two command, but when I executed `sudo apt-get update` I got

> The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 26C95CF201182252 Neo Technology Admins

Do you know why and what can I do?
Thanks

p.s. If I run `sudo apt-key list` I get

> pub   rsa4096 2016-10-26 [SC] [expired: 2019-10-26]
>         1EEF B876 7D49 24B8 6EAD  08A4 59D7 00E4 D37F 5F19
>   uid           [ expired] Neo4j Admins

Comment: The Neo4j signature has expired. Contact the admins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is now updated. You can redo:

`wget -O - https://debian.neo4j.org/neotechnology.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -`

or to update the apt keys list from the keyserver:

`sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keys.gnupg.net  D37F5F19 01182252`